# Is there a way of showing/indicating an updated tab from an extension/background page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for behaviour similar to pinned Gmail tabs, where tab head blinks when there's a new email and the tab is not in focus.

[chrome.windows.update(..)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) has a 'drawAttention' option. But [chrome.tabs.update(..)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) only has 'active' and 'highlight' options.

I couldn't locate a method of indicating an updated tab in the active window without switching to it/or highlighting it (which seems to have almost similar behaviour to active).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that highlighting is as far as `tabs` API goes.

You could use a content script to show an annoying animated favicon until the tab gets visible as a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that (injected content script to insert favicon) could be an option. Prefer not to go down that way, if I can afford it.

Any idea how the browser does it when Gmail tabs blink? Is it a native, browser-only method, or is Gmail doing some wizadry?

Comment: @AdiB That glowing tab effect is specific to pinned tabs, and happens when the page's title changes. This feature is not Chrome-specific, it also happens in Firefox, for instance.

Comment: @RobW Could you please make that into an answer? I believe it's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The glowing tab effect is specific to pinned tabs, and *only* happens when the page's title changes. This feature is not Chrome-specific, it also available in Firefox.

There is no way to get this effect for unpinned tabs, but if the tab is pinned, then you could change the page's title to get the desired effect via content script. To use this, you must declare the permissions to access the host.
Here is minimal example to achieve the goal:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    'document.title += ".";'
});
```

If you want to use this feature, I suggest to switch between two states (e.g. with trailing dot and without dot), to prevent the title from getting too long.

Unless the tab content is really updated, I recommend against using this trick, because the visual indicator is misleading when there is no update in the tab.

Alternative ugly ways to draw attentions to unpinned tabs with [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) are:

- Pin/unpin tab
- Move tabs across the tab strip
- Activate/deactive the tab